# Using "position" as index to access in a node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am studing the function position(), this give a number.

I would use the number of position() as a index to access in a sorted node.

I am using this instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="position()+50"/>
```

This, for example, if position is 1 give 51, if position is 2 give 52 etc.

I would access in a node using this index:

```
ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER[position()+50].
```

I'm using it in this context:

```
<body style="tab-interval:35.4pt">
    <div>
        <table  style="font-size:9pt; border-style:none; border-collapse:collapse; vertical-align:top; font-family:Univers Condensed;" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
                <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
                <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
                <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
                <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
                <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
                <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
                <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
                <td> <p>Internazionale</p></td>
                <td> <p>Italiano</p></td>
            </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//INTERNATIONAL_LIGHT_NUMBER">
            <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                <xsl:if test="position()&lt;='50'">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()+50"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()+100"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()+150"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>                        
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()+200"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                        </tr>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

for the first two column run very well, after dont run.

Using this method I write in the first column from 1 to 50, in the third column from 51 to 100, in the fifth column from 101 to 150 etc, but I wont write not a number but the content field of the node that correspond to number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER[position()+50]
```

That will never select or match anything, but if you store the current position in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
```

you can then use:

```
ITA_LIGHT_NUMBER[$position+50]
```

to address the node 50 places further down from the current one.

---

### Added:

***In response to your updated question:***

I don't think that's a good approach, but if you want to try it, try it along the lines of:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:sort/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 50">
        <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../item[$position+50]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../item[$position+100]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../item[$position+150]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="../item[$position+200]"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

which of course could be written more simply as:

```
<xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:sort/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= 50">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[50]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[100]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[150]"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::item[200]"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The larger problem with this method is that you are limiting yourself in both the horizontal (≤5 columns) and the vertical (≤50 rows) direction. Thus if you have more than 250 items, the remainder will be cut off; if you have significantly less, then the display will be uneven.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your precious collavobation, I update the question, because when I finish the first two column of 50 rows and I restart the other I am not able to write the contents of the field.